# Web Scraping Emails using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

new to web scraping (using python) and encountered a problem trying to get an email from a university's athletic department site.

I've managed to get to navigate to the email I want to extract but don't know where to go from here. When I print what I have, all I get is '' and not the actual text of the email.

I'm attaching what I have so far, let me know if it needs a better explanation.

Here's a link to an image of what I'm trying to scrape. [Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7rW6.png)
and the website: https://goheels.com/staff-directory

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ''

with open('websites.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read():
        urls += line

urls = list(urls.split())

print(urls)

for url in urls:

    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    try:

        body = soup.find(headers="col-staff_email category-0")
        links = body.a
        print(links)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'"This url didn\'t work:"  {url}')
```

Comment: Try printing soup (`print(soup)`), see what's the full html structure, and eventually post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emails are hidden inside a `<script>` element. With a little pushing, shoving, css selecting and string splitting you can get there:

```
for em in soup.select('td[headers*="col-staff_email"] script'):
    target = em.text.split('var firstHalf = "')[1]
    fh = target.split('";')[0]
    lh = target.split('var secondHalf = "')[1].split('";')[0]
    print(fh+ '@' +lh)
```

Output:

```
bubba.cunningham@unc.edu
molly.dalton@unc.edu
athgallo@unc.edu
dhollier@unc.edu
```

etc.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I guess my one question is how did you get "td[headers*="col-staff_email" using CSS selector and how is it iterating through a list? I thought .select just returns one value?

Comment: @Jean-PaulAzzopardi - `select()` returns a list; `select_one()` return only one elment (the first, if there are more than one).